# Youtube video to text to speach

Tags: video, youtube

I have a youtube video that I narrate but I always type a script to read off for my videos is there a way to use my voice from one of the videos and insert it into a text to speach program so I don't always have to read the script? I know the program might not be able to handle tones of voice like sarcasm but I can edit small parts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes...possibly, if there is enough to sample from your existing video voice-overs but, as it's your voice, there's no reason to only use your videos as a source and the Acapela-Group, for example, has developed a [Voice Factory](http://www.acapela-group.com/voices/custom-voice-creation/) for custom voice creation.

The main problem is that it will take time and money to do.

Try googling "text to speech sample my own voice" for other resources and methods and consider buying a quality text to speech application and quality sampled voice to use instead of your own. A quick Google of "high quality text to speech" will provide links to many options and demos.